# Number guess rounds

Tags: java, numbers

i wanted to do the guess the number game. For one round my programm works and I can guess a number. I want that the user can enter the amout of rounds (1-20) what he wants to play, but there is my problem this isn't working as thought. I tried to use a boolean but after I guessed the number for 1 round it doesn't begin the next round. 
The In function is similar to scanner, but I have a java class for that therefore I use that.

```
public class GuessNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("round 1-20");
    int roundTyped = In.readInt();

    int rndN = (int) (Math.random()*100)+1;
    int typedN = 0;
    int trys = 0;
    boolean active = true;
    int round = 0;

    while (active) {
        while (typedN != rndN) {
            trys++;
            System.out.println(trys + ". Versuch:");
            typedN = In.readInt();

            if(typedN < 1 || typedN > 100) {
                System.out.println("ungueltig");
            }else if(typedN < rndN) {
                System.out.println("groesser");
            }else if(typedN > rndN) {
                System.out.println("kleiner");
            }else if(typedN == rndN) {
                System.out.println("korrrekt");
            }
        }
        round++;
        if (round == roundTyped) {
            active = false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: boolean active = false; while (active == true) {  ask your self if this will ever got executed

Comment: I'd suggest you start with formatting your code properly. This will allow you to easily sport small mistakes http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Answer (score 0):

You set the number to be guessed only once at the start of the program. Therefore, after the user has guessed the correct number once, the remaining rounds will all be completed instantly (the condition of the inner while will always be true).
I would suggest you use a debugger to find problems like these. When you step through your program, it will immediately become obvious what is happening.

Comment: Ahh ok and how or where should I change it. And I use the debug method in eclipse but it don`t show me a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Having two while loops is unnecessary, you can put several conditions for the `while`, and you use 2 variables that will be the same `round` and `trys`.

But your biggest problem is that you actually set your active to `false` right before checking if it is `true`.

Try something like that :)

```
    System.out.println("round 1-20");
    int roundTyped = In.readInt();

    int rndN = (int) (Math.random()*100)+1;
    int typedN = 0;
    int nTrysAllowed = 10; // The max number of tries
    int trys = 0;
    int round = 0;

    while (round < roundTyped) {
        while (typedN != rndN && trys < nTrysAllowed) {
            trys++;
            System.out.println(trys + ". Versuch:");
            typedN = In.readInt();

            if(typedN<1 || typedN >100) {
                System.out.println("ungueltig");
            } else if(typedN < rndN) {
                System.out.println("groesser");
            } else if(typedN > rndN) {
                System.out.println("kleiner");
            } else {
                System.out.println("korrrekt");
            }
        }

        // Here you can reduce the max number of tries for example or do whatever you want. For example: 
        round++;
        if (typedN == rndN) {
            // New number to guess
            rndN = (int) (Math.random()*100)+1;
            // Difficulty
            nTrysAllowed--;
            trys = 0;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Game done you can't go to next round, you lose this one.");
            round = roundTyped;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That works but the problem I also will make a diffiulty which limit the trys and so this would be wrong or? :)

Comment: @JanM in what sense ? You can always make the trys go up faster for example

Comment: Yes but I also need for the next round a new random number

Comment: @JanM Ohh I understand now, so yeah your two loops were good ;-)
I will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried it but it the program but I can't try a second round it just stops

Comment: @JanM If you find the correct number you can go on the next round but otherwise I made it so that you can't play agin